# Titanium install DB

Tags: android, sqlite, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have some trouble with installing a database with [Ti.Database.install()](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Database-method-install). Here's what I'm doing:

- Open new default alloy project
- Add some code to `controllers/index.js`  so the file looks like this

  ```
  var db = Ti.Database.install('/testimusDB.sqlite', 'testimusDB'); 
  var rs = db.execute('SELECT * FROM testimusTable');
  db.close();

  while (rs.isValidRow())
  {
    var name = rs.fieldByName('name');
    var age = rs.fieldByName('age');
    alert(name + ' is ' + age + 'years old');
    rs.next();
  }

  rs.close();

  $.index.open();
  ```
- create a DB with FF Plugin SQLite Manager called testimusDB.sqlite
  and copy it to the REsources Folder of the Project
- Start the App via Titanium Studio on a Samsung S3

What I get is

```
   Runtime Error: LOCATION: [101,19] ti:/invoker.js
   MESSAGE: Uncaught Error: Resources/testimusDB.sqlite SOURCE: return
   delegate.apply(invoker._thisObj_,args);
```

People with the same problem solved it by reducing the size of the DB (mine is 64 KB) or by using absolute path (I tried absolute-/relative- path and sqlite-/db-/sql- suffix). Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Comment: Why are you putting it inside the Resources folder? That folder is autogenerated when using alloy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it: You can't use install() when you're using alloy! (If anybody knows an official source for this information please let me know). You need to use models to sync the database. [This guy](http://learnappcelerator.blogspot.in/2013/07/alloy-framework-use-preloaded-sqlite.html) and [this guide](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Alloy_Sync_Adapters_and_Migrations) helped me a lot.

Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Close connection to db at the end of operation:

```
rs.close();
db.close();
```

Size of the database doesn't matter. I'm using much bigger one: >10MB.